# Set DB result to public static inside a class

Tags: php

I have a class and inside the class I have a public static set as

```
public static $salt = '*nW5@Ipn(rXRPUy4KJMFK!o&HY4iOeAF0@CM!96X';
```

I need to rather query a DB, fetch the "key" from the result and set that result to the `public static $salt`

I am getting to the point where the DB connection is made, the result is found but I just don't know how to set the result the to the 
public static $salt

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically populating a static variable in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024282/dynamically-populating-a-static-variable-in-php)

Comment: An interesting solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693691/how-to-initialize-static-variables/4470002#4470002