# Define handler for call_user_func in class

Tags: php

This is very basic question, I have this class which says i can define my own handler which will alter the `callName()` function in the example below :

```
class MyClass
{
 protected static $callHandler;

 public static function callName($name){
        if (static::$callHandler) {
            return call_user_func(static::$callHandler, $name);
        }
     print $name;
  } 
}
```

I know i can do this :
    $class = new MyClass();
    $class->callName("Jonny");

But how do I define my own $callhandler in `call_user_func` and alter the outcome?

Comment: `MyClass::callName()` is a [static method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php). You should call it as `MyClass::callName("Jonny")`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @axiac, tell me how do i define $callHandler

Comment: Any function that receives one argument can be used as `$callHandler`. You have to add a (static) method to your class to set it, though.

Comment: Are you writing this class, or are you asking us how to alter `$callHandler` in this existing class…?

Comment: @deceze this is just an example, real code is very lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

These are the ways that come to my mind, you should choose the most appropriate one:

- Check the rest of the methods of the class if some kind of setter, initializer or magic setter method exists and use it.
- Extend `MyClass` and set `$callHandler` there.
- Extend `MyClass` and create some static initialization function, which you'll call afterwards to set the value.
- Use Reflection.

You can check these SO questions, they're similar: [How to initialize static variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693691/how-to-initialize-static-variables), [Dynamically populating a static variable in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024282/dynamically-populating-a-static-variable-in-php?lq=1).