# php initialize static variable with other static variable

Tags: php, variables, static-variables

I tried to initialize a static var with the content of another one and it seems to fail.

```
class Hey {
    static $user = "peter";
    static $home = '/home'.Hey::$user;

    // syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_STRING
```

Why does it fail and is there a way without an init-function or something else?

Comment: guys don't fool him ?! it's simply not possible as initializions must be constant they are not allowed to use variables at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Hey {
    static $user = "peter";
    static $home;
}
Hey::$home =  '/home'.Hey::$user;
```

or if $home is private:

```
class Hey {
    static $user = "peter";
    private static $home;
    static function init(){self::$home = '/home'.self::$user;}
}
Hey::init();
```

see [How to initialize static variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693691/php-how-to-initialize-static-variables?rq=1)