# FuelPHP - Using Core Classes in ORM Models

Tags: php, static-methods, fuelphp, fuelphp-orm

How can I use a *core classe* in my **ORM** Model ?

## Is working:

```
protected static $_properties  = array(
    'id',
    'user_id',
    'v_key' => array('default' => 'abc' ),
    'a_key' => array('default' => 'def' ),
    'created_at',
    'updated_at'
);
```

## Isn't working:

```
protected static $_properties  = array(
    'id',
    'v_key' => array('default' => Str::random('alnum', 6) ),
    'a_key' => array('default' => Str::random('alnum', 6) ),
    'created_at',
    'updated_at'
);
```

[image: The error]

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Your actual problem here is that you can't perform function calls when making static assignments in PHP. [How to initialize static variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693691/php-how-to-initialize-static-variables)

Comment: A common work around for this is to use fuel's `_init()` method to set up "static" variables, so set an empty value for your default then do something like `static::$_properties['v_key']['default'] = Str::random()`

Comment: Is it _syntaxically_ right to override parameters like that? What do you think of using an observer "after_create" ?

Comment: An observer would not work as you are assigning `static` properties their values.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I used an observer to do that.

## /classes/observer/session.php

```
<?php

namespace Orm;

use Str;

class Observer_Session extends Observer {
  public function after_create(Model $session) {

    $session->v_key = Str::random('alnum', 6);
    $session->a_key = Str::random('alnum', 6);

  }
```

## /classes/model/session.php

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically set default values, you can override the forge method in your session model:

```php
public static function forge($data = array(), $new = true, $view = null, $cache = true)
{

    $data = \Arr::merge(array(
        'v_key'      => \Str::random('alnum', 6),
        'a_key'      => \Str::random('alnum', 6),
    ), $data);

    return parent::forge($data, $new, $view, $cache);

}
```