# In cakephp how to use internationalization in class variable?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using cakephp and I got an error when I use internationalization in class variable.

My class is :

```
class Util extends Object
{
    public static $options = array(
        'Traffic Limit' => __('Traffic Limit'),
        'Uptime Limit' => __('Uptime Limit'),
        'IP Address' => __('IP Address'),
        'MAC Address' => __('MAC Address')
    );
}
```

When I use internationalization in class varriable it shows error :

```
Error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'
```

I have also try 'true' as second parameter in internationlization but same error I received.

When I use this variable with internationalization in class method

```
public static function getWispUserAttributeNames()
{
    $options = array(
        'Traffic Limit' => __('Traffic Limit'),
        'Uptime Limit' => __('Uptime Limit'),
        'IP Address' => __('IP Address'),
        'MAC Address' => __('MAC Address')
    );
    return $options;
}
```

it works perfectally.

Is there is a way to use internationalization in class variable?

Comment: got the same problem but didnt find out the reason.

Comment: I thinks global variable not call function __(). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Util extends Object
    {
        public $options = array(
            'Traffic Limit' => __('Traffic Limit'),
            'Uptime Limit' => __('Uptime Limit'),
            'IP Address' => __('IP Address'),
            'MAC Address' => __('MAC Address')
        );
    }
```

I don't think you should use "static" for variable.

Comment: the question is something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use complex expressions in initializers in PHP, So next expression is wrong, no matter it's static or not:

```
public static $options = array(
    'Traffic Limit' => __('Traffic Limit'),
    'Uptime Limit' => __('Uptime Limit'),
    'IP Address' => __('IP Address'),
    'MAC Address' => __('MAC Address')
);
```

but you can do a trick for static case:

After describing class:

```
class Util extends Object
{
    public static $options = array();
}

//do assign, at the bottom of file

Util::$options = array(
    'Traffic Limit' => __('Traffic Limit'),
    'Uptime Limit' => __('Uptime Limit'),
    'IP Address' => __('IP Address'),
    'MAC Address' => __('MAC Address')
);
```

See this: [How to initialize static variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693691/how-to-initialize-static-variables)