# PHP static variable as a result of another function

Tags: php, variables, scope

I am trying to define a PHP class with some static variables. I am trying to do the following to avoid using globals.

```
class class_Name{
  private static $var1 = is_plugin_inactive('plugin/plugin.php'); //check if WordPress has this plugin active
  public static function doSomeStuff(){
    echo $var1;
  }
}
//init class
class_Name::doSomeStuff();
```

This always get's me an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in my_file.php` at line where I am defining the static variable.

Any help please.

Comment: Class vars defined there must be constant expressions.  Try assigning it in the function.

Comment: I need the variable to be defined outside the `doSomeStuff` function so I can use it in several other functions. Thanks

Comment: Well, you can't do it there.

Comment: Typo. You call `doSomeStuff` but in the class the name is `doSomStuff`.

Comment: Edited, please other suggestions?

Comment: "__Class vars defined there must be constant expressions. Try assigning it in the function.__" Do you need more suggestions ?

Comment: @user3584460 can you please provide a easy example for me, I will test and mark your answer.

Comment: setting class properties at that point is not allowed by the language as @AbraCadaver mentioned.  You could add a setter function to explicitly set it prior to calling any of your other functions

Comment: Please refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693691/how-to-initialize-static-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of your exact situation, but can you do:

```
class class_Name {
    private static $var1 = null;   

    //check if WordPress has this plugin active
    public static function doSomeStuff(){
        if(is_null(self::$var1))
            self::$var1 = is_plugin_inactive('plugin/plugin.php');
        echo self::$var1;
    }
}
```

Basically call the function like you are wanting to, but initialize it if its not already?

Answer (score 1):

if you like to save a non constant expression in $var1 you need to set in from a method, for example an init method:

```
class class_Name {

    private static $var1 = null;

    public static function init() {
        self::$var1 = is_plugin_inactive('plugin/plugin.php');
    }

    public static function doSomeStuff() {
        echo self::$var1;
    }

}

class_Name::init();

class_Name::doSomeStuff();
```