# How to cast multiple array elements to object

Tags: php

I'm trying to create an array containing multiple objects.

I wrote this code (it's a member of an existing class)

```
public static $Roles = [
    (object) ['code' => 'SO', 'name' => 'Socio'],
    (object) ['code' => 'RESP', 'name' => 'Responsabile zona'],
    (object) ['code' => 'AMM', 'name' => 'Amministratore'],
];
```

but I get this error:

> syntax error, unexpected '(object)' (object) (T_OBJECT_CAST),
>   expecting ')'

on the second line.

I thought this should work, because I already used the same cast syntax to define associative array elements:

```
return view('edit-headquarter', [
  'hq' => (object)['name' => '', 'id' => 0],
  'submitAction' => 'insert'
]);
```

I'm doing something wrong?

EDIT: I'm using PHP 5.4.45

I'm not sure, but [this can be related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693691/how-to-initialize-static-variables)  as suggested by Martin Persson

Comment: I think this has something to do with your php version. If it doesn't work, you may think about declaring an Stdclass object or, even better, to implement a function that returns an stdclass object from the provided array. (also, another possible trick is to json_decode a json_encode(array))

Comment: @user340764 , where it works fine? https://3v4l.org/pXo2o

Comment: What's the point? You convert arrays to `stdClass` objects which are just arrays with less features and a different syntax. They do not provide any useful OOP feature. You better create a class `Role` and pass the values of `code` and `name` as arguments to its constructor. There is no need for conversions any more and you can add more features to them as needed.

Comment: @axiac: I'm learning PHP, so I'm exploring possibilities. The point is to be able to use o::$Roles[0]->code in the same way I do with other object, just for consistency. I didn't understood why this isn't working, since I'm using same syntax in other place, as I said

Comment: As the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/it/language.oop5.static.php) say "Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed."

Comment: @AndreaParodi : for your task, I think the closest you can get is something like this: https://3v4l.org/nZtOE (mostly because you cannot use expressions in static declarations, as Federico said)

Comment: @briosheje: thank you, I already refactored to declare the property uninitialized and then fill it later...

Comment: I strongly recommend that you upgrade to PHP 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using PHP version below v5.6, then you will not be allowed to have an expression as a default value for class members. Other than that, I don't see anything wrong with the way you have declared it.

Comment: I extracted the expression to a variable, and used that variable as the default value. The object now creates just fine. I receive an error when defining the stating property.

Comment: Ok, as suggested by Federico, I neither can use a variable as initializer. That make sense... Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

To cast an associative array to object you can use a bit dirty, but widely used

`$obj = json_decode(json_encode($arr));`