# PHP Ternary operator with static call

Tags: php

When I do:

```
$foo = (1 === 1) ? 'one' : 'not one';
```

Following expression gives me error though:

```
public static $relationsData = [
    'tasks' => (Module::isEnabled('Task')) ? [self::HAS_MANY, Task::class, 'foreignKey' => 'created_by'] : [],
];
```

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: What kind of error does it gives you ? because as long as the function returns a boolean, it si possible.

Comment: Getting `syntax error, unexpected '('`

Comment: Show more code.  The error code is not here.

Comment: The code that actually causes this error probably lies above this code and only manifests as an error on this line. We need to see the code above this.

Comment: i have updated the question with actual code that is giving error.

Comment: You won't be able to set the static property that way. You can only use expressions that can be evaluated at compile time. It doesn't have anything to do with the ternary, though.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693691/how-to-initialize-static-variables?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The error you encounter is probably related to `Module::isEnabled('Bar')` and not to ternary operator. Whatever is condition of the ternary operator is evaluated first and ternary operator simply uses the result of that evaluation. Simply having `Foo::bar()` as condition should not cause any problem.

Edit after OP's update:
As others have said, the problem here is you are assigning a non-trivial expression to a static class variable. The ternary operator is merely doing its job.